# SQL Server : delete duplicates depending on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple SQL query

```
SELECT 
    t.rowId, t.colid,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [Datetime], 108) [Datetime] 
FROM
    Events e 
INNER JOIN
    tempEvent t ON e.employeeid = t.kodp 
                AND CAST(e.[datetime] AS DATE) = t.data 
WHERE 
    ControlPointid IN (SELECT ControlPointID 
                       FROM ControlPoints 
                       WHERE Name LIKE '%POR%') 
    AND EventTypeId = 1 
    AND EmployeeId = 504;
```

And here are the results:

```
rowId   colid   Datetime
-------------------------
32        7      06:53
32        13     06:56
32        14     06:53
32        17     06:51
32        17     10:50
32        18     06:50
32        19     06:48
32        10     06:50
32        20     06:51
```

As you can see, there are two rows with same `t.rowId` and `t.colId`. The question is, how to delete second row of this occurrence?

Comment: Is `MySQL` or `SQL-Server` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar It's SQL-Server. Adding mysql tag was a missclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation, but you need to decide which values you want to keep: To delete second occurrent use Min instead of Max.

```
select t.rowId, t.colid,
       min(convert(varchar(5), [Datetime], 108)) as [Datetime] 
from Events e inner join
     tempEvent t 
     on e.employeeid = t.kodp and
        cast(e.[datetime] as date) = t.data 
where ControlPointid in (select ControlPointID
                         from ControlPoints
                         where Name like '%POR%'
                        ) and
      EventTypeId = 1 And EmployeeId = 504
group by t.rowId, t.colid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the CTE you can group by the `t.rowId ,t.colid` and get your expected result:

```
;WITH ResultData AS (
    SELECT  t.rowId, t.colid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [Datetime], 108) [Datetime],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.rowId, t.colid ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [Datetime], 108) ASC) RowNumber
    FROM Events e
    INNER JOIN tempEvent t ON e.employeeid = t.kodp AND cast(e.[datetime] AS DATE) = t.data
    WHERE ControlPointid IN (SELECT ControlPointID FROM ControlPoints WHERE NAME LIKE '%POR%' )
        AND EventTypeId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 504
)
SELECT rowId, colid, [Datetime]
FROM ResultData
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you look for RowNumber > 1 since those are the ones you want to delete? (or apply a not in...)

Comment: @jens actually user wants to delete row from his select query :-)

Comment: @Arulkumar Your way works too. Thanks for your answer.